# Can I do `ret` instruction from code at _start in MacOS? Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, assembly, return, entry-point

I am wondering if it is legal to return with `ret` from a program's entry point.

Example with NASM:

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
ret

; Linux: nasm -f elf64 foo.asm -o foo.o && ld foo.o
; OS X:  nasm -f macho64 foo.asm -o foo.o && ld foo.o -lc -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 -e _start -o foo
```

`ret` pops a return address from the stack and jumps to it.

But are the top bytes of the stack a valid return address at the program entry point, or do I have to call exit?

Also, the program above does not segfault on OS X. Where does it return to?

Comment: No, you can't. You'll need to do an exit system call because there is no return address on the stack in this case. If you link to the _C_ runtime libraries and change your function to `main` then it will work because `ret` would return to the _C_ runtime which in turn eventually does its own exit system call.

Comment: @MichaelPetch You can post as answer I'll accept. Do you know why it doesn't crash on OS X if the address is not valid ?

Comment: That depends on your operating system.  In DOS, it's legal, on UNIX generally not.

Comment: @fuz : that depends. DOS EXE you wouldn't be able to do a `ret` but a COM program would since a DOS COM program has a 16-bit word placed on the stack at 0xfffe with the value 0x0000. When you do `ret` it return back to 0x0000 in the current segment. 0x0000 (in the PSP) contains an `int 20h` instruction that in turn terminates the COM program. EXEs don't have any return address passed on the stack so a `ret` will likely hang/crash DOS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### MacOS Dynamic Executables

When you are using **MacOS** and link with:

```
ld foo.o -lc -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 -e _start -o foo
```

you are getting a **dynamically** loaded version of your code. `_start` isn't the true entry point, the dynamic loader is. The dynamic loader as one of its last steps does *C/C++/Objective-C* runtime initialization, and then calls your specified entry point specified with the `-e` option. The Apple documentation about [*Forking and Executing the Process*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachOTopics/1-Articles/executing_files.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001829-SW1) has these paragraphs:

> A Mach-O executable file contains a header consisting of a set of load commands. For programs that use shared libraries or frameworks, one of these commands specifies the location of the linker to be used to load the program. If you use Xcode, this is always /usr/lib/dyld, the standard OS X dynamic linker.
>
> When you call the execve routine, the kernel first loads the specified program file and examines the mach_header structure at the start of the file. The kernel verifies that the file appear to be a valid Mach-O file and interprets the load commands stored in the header. The kernel then loads the dynamic linker specified by the load commands into memory and executes the dynamic linker on the program file.
>
> The **dynamic linker** loads all the shared libraries that the main program links against (the dependent libraries) and **binds enough of the symbols to start the program**. **It then calls the entry point function**. At build time, the static linker adds the **standard entry point function** to the main executable file **from** the object file **/usr/lib/crt1.o**. This function **sets up the runtime environment state for the kernel and calls static initializers for C++ objects, initializes the Objective-C runtime**, and **then** calls the **program’s main function**

In your case that is `_start`. In this environment where you are creating a dynamically linked executable you can do a `ret` and have it return back to the code that called `_start` which does an exit system call for you. This is why it doesn't crash. If you review the generated object file with `gobjdump -Dx foo` you should get:

```
start address 0x0000000000000000

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000001  0000000000001fff  0000000000001fff  00000fff  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, CODE
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000001000 g       03 ABS    01 0010 __mh_execute_header
0000000000001fff g       0f SECT   01 0000 [.text] _start
0000000000000000 g       01 UND    00 0100 dyld_stub_binder

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001fff <_start>:
    1fff:       c3                      retq
```

Notice that `start address` is 0. And the code at 0 is `dyld_stub_binder`. This is the dynamic loader stub that eventually sets up a *C* runtime environment and then calls your entry point `_start`. If you don't override the entry point it defaults to `main`.

---

### MacOS Static Executables

If however you build as a **static** executable, there is no code executed before your entry point and `ret` should crash since there is no valid return address on the stack. In the documentation quoted above is this:

> For programs that use shared libraries or frameworks, one of these commands specifies the location of the linker to be used to load the program.

A statically built executable doesn't use the dynamic loader `dyld` with `crt1.o` embedded in it. **CRT** = *C* runtime library which covers C++/Objective-C as well on MacOS. The processes of dealing with dynamic loading are not done, *C/C++/Objective-C* initialization code is not executed, and control is transferred directly to your entry point.

To build statically drop the `-lc` (or `-lSystem`) from the linker command and add `-static` option:

```
ld foo.o -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 -e _start -o foo -static
```

If you run this version it should produce a segmentation fault. `gobjdump -Dx foo` produces

```
start address 0x0000000000001fff

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000001  0000000000001fff  0000000000001fff  00000fff  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, CODE
  1 LC_THREAD.x86_THREAD_STATE64.0 000000a8  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000198  2**0
                  CONTENTS
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000001000 g       03 ABS    01 0010 __mh_execute_header
0000000000001fff g       0f SECT   01 0000 [.text] _start

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001fff <_start>:
    1fff:       c3                      retq
```

You should notice `start_address` is now 0x1fff. 0x1fff is the entry point you specified (`_start`). There is no dynamic loader stub as an intermediary.

---

### Linux

Under **Linux** when you specify your own entry point it will segmentation fault whether you are building as a static or shared executable. There is good information on how ELF executables are run on Linux in this [article](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/) and the [dynamic linker documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so). The key point that should be observed is that the Linux one makes no mention of doing *C/C++/Objective-C* runtime initialisation unlike the MacOS dynamic linker documentation.

The key difference between the Linux dynamic loader (ld.so) and the MacOS one (dynld) is that the MacOS dynamic loader performs *C/C++/Objective-C* startup initialization by including the entry point from `crt1.o`. The code in `crt1.o` then transfers control to the entry point you specified with `-e` (default is `main`). In Linux the dynamic loader makes no assumption about the type of code that will be run. After the shared objects are processed and initialized control is transferred directly to the entry point.

---

### Stack Layout at Process Creation

FreeBSD (on which MacOS is based) and Linux share one thing in common. When loading 64-bit executables the layout of the user stack when a process is created is the same. The stack for 32-bit processes is similar but pointers and data are 4 bytes wide, not 8.

[image]

Although there isn't a return address on the stack, there is other data representing the number of arguments, the arguments, environment variables, and other information. This layout is **not** the same as what the `main` function in *C/C++* expects. It is part of the *C* startup code to convert the stack at process creation to something compatible with the *C* calling convention and the expectations of the function `main` (`argc`, `argv`, `envp`).

I wrote more information on this subject in this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37230461/3857942) that shows how a **statically** linked MacOS executable can traverse through the program arguments passed by the kernel at process creation.

Comment: Nice answer. Do you have some links that explain this and how entry point is called in OS X / Linux with static and dynamic executables?

Comment: @Bilow I've added information specific to Apple about the load process (static and dynamic). I've added a link to the Apple docs and a snippet from those docs about the process. I've also exapnded and clarified the dynamic linker on Linux including some external documentation and information.

Answer (score 2):

Suplementing what Michael Petch already answered:
from runnable Mach-o executable perspective program launch happens either due to load command `LC_MAIN` (most modern executables since 10.7) which utilises `DYLD` in the process or backward compatible load command `LC_UNIXTHREAD`. The former is the variant where your `ret` is allowed and in fact preferable because you return control to DYLD __mh_execute_header. This will be followed by a buffer flush.
Alternatively to `ret` you can use system exit call either through undocumented `syscall` kernel API (64bit, `int 0x80` for 32bit) or DYLD wrapper C lib doing it(documented).
If your executable is not utilising `LC_MAIN` you're left with legacy `LC_UNIXTHREAD` where you have no alternative to system exit call , `ret` will cause a `segmentation fault`.

Comment: The syscall interface is documented.even for 64-bit. `syscalls.master` maintains a list of the calls and the parameters. The 32-bit interface documentation is more easily found if you read the FreeBSD documentation (On which MacOS is based). Parameters pushed on stack with a dummy 4 bytes allocated before `int 0x80`. The 64-bit syscall calling convention uses the 64-bit System V ABI kernel calling convention (same as Linux). The difference between 32-bit and 64-bit system call numbers is that on 64-bit you have to add 0x2000000 to the system call numbers.

Comment: If I recall correctly MacOS 64 bit system calls use `r10` for `4th arg` vs `rcx` under regular System V ABI.

Comment: You may have missed the word `kernel` calling convention when I said _64-bit System V ABI_. You will find the register calling convention for syscall (including the fact that RCX and R11 are clobbered) documented in the [64-bit System V ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) . Section A.2.1 states _2. A system-call is done via the syscall instruction. The kernel destroys
registers %rcx and %r11._ and _The kernel interface uses %rdi,
%rsi, %rdx, %r10, %r8 and %r9._

Comment: Cool, that explains the difference. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: No problem. I had upvoted your answer. I was just making an observation.