# Tell 'ld' dyld_stub_binder is no longer in libSystem.dyld but in libSystem.B.dyld

Tags: macos, assembly, linker, x86-64, mach-o

I am trying to re-create the Launchpad executable and so far everything seems right except I get this warning when I run `ld`:

Assembling/Linking with:

```
as myprogram.s -o myprogram.o
ld myprogram.o -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12 -e _start -framework Foundation -framework ApplicationServices -o myprogram

ld: symbol dyld_stub_binder not found (normally in libSystem.dylib).  Needed to perform lazy binding to function _CoreDockSendNotification for architecture x86_64
```

Here is my code (sorry NASM guys, AT&T syntax here):

```
.section __DATA, __const
.section __TEXT, __text
.globl _start
_start:
pushq %rbp
movq %rbp, %rsp
lea lpToggle_cfstring_(%rip), %rdi
xor %esi, %esi
callq _CoreDockSendNotification
mov %rax, %r14
xor %rdi, %rdi
mov $0x2000001, %rax
syscall

.section __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
lpToggle: .asciz    "com.apple.launchpad.toggle"
.section __DATA,__cfstring
lpToggle_cfstring_:
    .quad   ___CFConstantStringClassReference
    .long   1992                    
    .space  4
    .quad   lpToggle
    .quad   26
```

I have updated to the latest version of of both xcode and the command line tools, I have tried changing `_start` to `_main`, I have tried to link libSystem.B.dyld directly (both with and without the '.dyld' extension):

`ld lp.o -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12 -e _start -framework Foundation -framework ApplicationServices -L/usr/lib/ -llibSystem.B.dyld -o lp`

`ld lp.o -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12 -e _start -framework Foundation -framework ApplicationServices -llibSystem.B.dyld -o lp`

`ld lp.o -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12 -e _start -framework Foundation -framework ApplicationServices  -o lp -l/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dyld`

`ld lp.o -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12 -e _start -framework Foundation -framework ApplicationServices  -o lp -libSystem.B.dyld`

To which I get:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/lib/ -llibSystem.B.dyld'
```

or

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-l/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dyld'
```

or

```
ld: warning: library not found for option '-l/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dyld'
```

Depending which one I try.

I even tried using `ld` directly from the `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin` directory to see if there was a symlink issue between new and legacy

I used lldb to dump the symtab of libSystem.dyld and sure enough the line that contains:

```
`[  108] 108 X Undefined 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x00010000 dyld_stub_binder`
```

Which means it has a and `index`/`user id` of `108`, the `X` means it is externally defined (probably is libSystem.B), `type` of `Undefined`, 'File Address/Value' of '0x0' no `Load Address`, and a flag of `0x00010000`.

I loaded the Launchpad executable in Hopper to see what it was going on but it wasn't of much help (except that it told me dyld_stub_binder was in libSystem.B.dyld).

Not sure if this is pertinent but in the actual Launchpad header contains:

```
                         ; Load Command 4
                         ; 
    0000000100000410     struct __macho_dyld_info_command {
                             LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY,   // LC_DYLD_INFO or LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY
                             0x30,                // sizeof(struct dyld_info_command)
                             0x2000,              // file offset to rebase info 
                             0x8,                 // size of rebase info  
                             0x2008,              // file offset to binding info  
                             0x40,                // size of binding info 
                             0x0,                 // file offset to weak binding info  
                             0x0,                 // size of weak binding info 
                             0x2048,              // file offset to lazy binding info
                             0x20,                // size of lazy binding infs
                             0x2068,              // file offset to lazy binding info
                             0x20                 // size of lazy binding infs
                         }


                        ;Load command 7

00000001000004a8         struct __macho_dylinker_command {
                             LC_LOAD_DYLINKER,  // LC_ID_DYLINKER, LC_LOAD_DYLINKER or LC_DYLD_ENVIRONMENT
                             0x20,  // includes pathname string
                             0xc    // dynamic linker's path name (should be 12)
                         }
00000001000004b4         db         "/usr/lib/dyld", 0
00000001000004c2         db  0x00 ; '.'
00000001000004c3         db  0x00 ; '.'
00000001000004c4         db  0x00 ; '.'
00000001000004c5         db  0x00 ; '.'
00000001000004c6         db  0x00 ; '.'
00000001000004c7         db  0x00 ; '.'
```

In the `_stub_helper` section (which looks like some sort of infinite-ish loop completely skipping the middle 4 instructions):

```
0000000100000f80   lea,  qword [dyld_stub_binder_100001000+8]; CODE XREF=0x100000f95
0000000100000f87   push  r11
0000000100000f89   jmp   qword [dyld_stub_binder_100001000] ; dyld_stub_binder
0000000100000f8f   db         0x90
0000000100000f90   push       0x0
0000000100000f95   jmp        0x100000f80
```

In the `__DATA__nl_symbol_ptr` section :

```
0000000100001000         dq  dyld_stub_binder  ; DATA XREF=0x100000f89
0000000100001008         dq  0x0000000000000000 ; DATA XREF=0x100000f80
```

In the `External Symbols` segment:

```
                 dyld_stub_binder:
0000000100005010         db  0x00 ; '.' ; in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib, CODE XREF=0x100000f89DATA XREF=dyld_stub_binder_100001000
0000000100005011         db  0x00 ; '.'
0000000100005012         db  0x00 ; '.'
0000000100005013         db  0x00 ; '.'
0000000100005014         db  0x00 ; '.'
0000000100005015         db  0x00 ; '.'
0000000100005016         db  0x00 ; '.'
0000000100005017         db  0x00 ; '.'
```

What is more interesting is that if I compile with gcc:

```
gcc -arch x86_64 -e _start -framework Foundation -framework ApplicationServices lp.s
```

It will build with no problems however will segfault at some point during runtime. I say at some point because if I load it with `lldb a.out` and do the `run` command, it executes just as it should, no segfault. So it is hard to find out what is going on where exactly.<s>My hunch is that `lldb` is *pointing* my application to the correct`dyld_stub_binder` but I could be wrong.</s>

However it runs perfectly fine if I run `sudo ./myfile` on the `gcc` build. What is `gcc` doing that `ld` is not? Or is it something in the `as` command?

I am still relatively new to using core macOS assembly so any pointers would be helpful!

P.S. I did also try `-no_weak_imports` but that did not work either

Comment: It's `.dylib`, not `.dyld`. Also `/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib` is a symlink to `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib`, so your problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: There is only one `dyld_stub_binder` per MacOS version. As a workaround if you do a `-bind_at_load` you don't need `dyld_stub_binder` at all

Comment: @Siguza I retried everything with the `.dylib` extension and still got the same results

Comment: @Kamil.S I added `-bind_at_load` to my `ld` command it still got the same `ld: symbol dyld_stub_binder not found...` as mentioned before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ld myprogram.o -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12 -e _start -framework Foundation -framework ApplicationServices -o myprogram` is missing `-l` search option for `libSystem.B` library.
Add either of these:

```
-lsystem.b
-lsystem
-lc
-lm
-ld
```

All are synonyms which will solve missing `LC_LOAD_DYLIB(libSystem.B.dylib)` load command. Btw your program works :-)

Comment: I thought this question would forever go unresolved. Thank you so much! I was able to get this to compile with gcc.  If you are at all interested, I have updated the code since posting here and put it up on github https://github.com/jslegendre/asm-launchpad

Comment: If you are into having full control of the binary executable down to single byte you can step it even further and get rid of `ld` altogether and craft the `Mach-o` format manually.

Comment: I saw that you forked my project. I am open to PRs if you would like to do that :)

Comment: I noticed you're doing an exit system call, since you're targeting MacOS 10.7 & above this can be simplified to `ret` . See my answer here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47810074/5329717

Comment: Thank you for that! I just updated a couple of the asm projects on my github to use `ret` instead of the exit syscall